# Access 2013 Cannot Set Lookup Display Control to Text Box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have added a new field to an existing database and set the Data Type to Yes/No as shown in Pic1.

[image: Pic1]

This defaults to Check Box. If I then try and select Text Box (as shown Pic2) it immediately reverts to Check Box. Combo Box can be selected successfully.

[image: Pic2]

Can someone advise why I cannot select Text Box? There are already other fields configured in this manner in my database. Also of note if I change these other fields to Check Box and try to change them back to Text Box, they also revert to Check Box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to confirm the change in behaviour between Access 2010 and Access 2013. Access 2010 allows us to choose "Text Box" for a `Yes/No` field. In Access 2013 the "Text Box" option is still there in the drop-down list, but when selected it immediately switches to "Check Box".

I'm afraid that's just the way Access 2013 works. If you *really need* to make the change you could try to locate a machine with Access 2010 and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm fairly new to Access so thought I was doing something wrong. I don't have to do it I was just trying to be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

I am facing the same problem. For some reason you cannot choose text box as lookup option.

There are two workarounds:
Choose combo box and

- Row Source Type: Value List
- Row Source: -1;Text for yes;0;Text for no
- Column Count: 2
- Column Widths: 0

[Source, from MS answers forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/yesno-data-type-custom-formatting-why-cant-i/17306081-b300-4e89-a46d-90306093841c)

Or select datasheet view, click fields under table tools, select more fields and go to Yes/No then select Yes/No. Now you can choose text box as look up option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :
    CurrentDb().TableDefs("YourTable").Fields("YourField").Properties("DisplayControl")=109